# How to strictly prove that $~f ( x ) = ( 1+x ) ^{d}~$ is represented in 2 terms as $~x \approx0~$ is held? Binomial series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations, approximation

$$  f \left( x \right)  := \left( 1+x \right) ^{d} ~~ \leftarrow~~ d \in\mathbb{R}  $$

I came across the problem of Maclaurin expansion.

$$  f \left( x \right) = \sum_{ i=0 }^{ \infty  } \frac{  f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right) \cdot x ^{i}  }{  i ! }   $$

$$  f ^{\left( 0 \right) }\left( x \right) =\left( 1+x \right) ^{d} $$

$$  f ^{\left(  1\right) }\left( x \right)=\left( d \right) \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-1} $$

$$  f ^{\left(  2\right) }\left( x \right)=\left( d \right) \left( d-1 \right) \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-2} $$

$$  f ^{\left(  3\right) }\left( x \right)=\left( d \right) \left( d-1 \right) \left( d-2 \right) \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-3} $$

$$  \therefore ~~ f^{\left( i \right) }\left( x \right) = \left\{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{i-1  }\left(d-j \right) \right\} \cdot \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-i}   $$

For instance , imagine that we set $~ d=-\frac{  3  }{  2  }  ~$

$$   f^{\left( i \right) }\left( x \right) = \left\{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{i-1  }\left(\left( -\frac{  3  }{  2  }  \right) -j \right) \right\} \cdot \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-i}   $$

$$ = \left\{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{ i-1 } \left( -\frac{  3  }{  2  } -j \right)  \right\} \cdot \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-i} $$

$$ = \left\{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{ i-1 } \left( \left( -1 \right) \left( \frac{  3  }{  2  } +j\right) \right)  \right\} \cdot \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-i} $$

$$ = \left( -1 \right)^{i}  \left\{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{ i-1 } \left( \frac{  3  }{  2  } +j\right)   \right\} \cdot \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-i} $$

$$ = f^{\left( i \right) }\left( x \right) =  \left( -1 \right)^{i}  \left\{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{ i-1 } \left( \frac{  3  }{  2  } +j\right)   \right\} \cdot \left( 1+x \right) ^{d-i}$$

Imagine we set $~ x=0 ~$

$$  f^{\left( i \right) }\left( 0 \right) =  \left( -1 \right)^{i}  \left\{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{ i-1 } \left( \frac{  3  }{  2  } +j\right)   \right\} \cdot \left( 1+0 \right) ^{d-i}$$

$$ =  \left( -1 \right)^{i}  \left\{ \underbrace{\color{blue}{\prod_{ j=0 }^{ i-1 } \left( \frac{  3  }{  2  } +j\right)} }_{ \color{black}{\text{This value}} ~ \propto ~i }  \right\} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{This value diverges to infinity}  $$

Nextly we consider each term of Maclaurin series.

$$ \frac{  f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right) \cdot x ^{i}  }{  i ! }  $$

I've been known that as $~ x \approx 0  ~$ is held , we can assume the below rightmost formula.

$$  f \left( x \right) = \sum_{ i=0 }^{ \infty  } \frac{  f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right) \cdot x ^{i}  }{  i  !}  \approx  \sum_{ i=0 }^{ 1  } \frac{  f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right) \cdot x ^{i}  }{  i!  } $$

One of the reason(s) that the above rightmost term is held is that $~ x^{\text{index greater than 1} } \approx 0 ~$ is held , can be said . But still I am concerning the term which I colored with blue .

$$ \frac{  f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right) \cdot x ^{i}  }{  i ! }= \frac{  1  }{  i!  } \cdot \left( \color{red}{ f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right)}\right) \cdot \left( \color{green}{ x ^{i}}   \right)  ~~ \leftarrow~~ ~~   \text{Red one diverges to infinity and green one converges to zero}~~  $$

Why this term can be said to converges to zero?

But it is said that $~ f \left( x \right) = \left( 1+x \right) ^{d}  ~$  can be represented with 2 terms as $~ x \approx 0 ~$

What is going on?

Comment: Note that you divide $f^{(i)}(0)$ by $i!$ which also diverges to infinity.

Comment: Ahh . I missed that.

Comment: Of course you still have to compare the rates of divergence.

Comment: I noticed that as $~d~$ takes a zero or a positive value , then the numerator will absolutely takes an zero . However the remained problem is as $~d~$ is a negative value .

Comment: Yes, because in that case $(1+x)^d$ is just a polynomial (classical case of the binomail theorem). For the general case, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence

Comment: Aohh. Thank youu.